# What would happen in this scenario about EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

Assume we have an ideal reflex glass (it passes 50% of the light and reflects 50% of it). we emmit two rays "1" and "2" (as shown in the figure) perpendicular to each other with a Pi phase difference (their fields are gonna cancel each other on the glass. so what would happen? what waves would propagate after this interaction? I think there shouldn't be any wave propagating from the right side of the glass to the right.

[image: Figure of scenario; Red lines: waves , blue line: reflex glass]

Comment: Set a system of coordinates x,y,z and note that $\mathbf E \times \mathbf B = \mathbf k$, and $\mathbf E$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf B$

Answer (score 1):

Classically, both rays will come out of the same side every time, but in quantum optics, they come out together on either side. It's called the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong–Ou–Mandel_effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect)).